# How to move Java REST application to Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have REST API Java application and want move it to cloud.

But I don't understand which tutorial use. 
I already have docker image in Container Registry made by Jib and want connect it with some cloud database (Cloud SQL/Spanner).

How change this connection props to cloud?

```
db.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
db.username=usrname
db.password=pswd
db.entity.package = com.example.model
```

Comment: Where do you want to deploy your container?

Comment: I want deploy it to Kubernetes

Answer (score 1):

We do this through Cloud SQL Proxy docker image: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-docker

> 1. Enable the Cloud SQL Admin API.
> 2. Install the mysql client on the Compute Engine instance or client machine, if it is not already installed.
> 3. If needed, install the Docker client
>      4.Install the Proxy Docker image from the Google Container Registry.
> 4. If you are running the Proxy Docker image on a local machine (not a Compute Engine instance), or your Compute Engine instance does not have the proper scopes, create a Google Cloud Platform service account.
> 5. Go to the Cloud SQL Instances page in the Google Cloud Console.
> 6. Select the instance to open its Instance details page and copy the Instance connection name.
> 7. Start the proxy.

```
docker run -d \
  -v <PATH_TO_KEY_FILE>:/config \
  -p 127.0.0.1:3306:3306 \
  gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.16 /cloud_sql_proxy \
  -instances=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>=tcp:0.0.0.0:3306 - credential_file=/config
```

> 9. Start the client
>      `mysql -u <USERNAME> -p --host 127.0.0.1`

Then connect using

```
db.driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/db
db.username=usrname
db.password=pswd
db.entity.package = com.example.model
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reach a CloudSQL database from a GKE cluster, you have 2 solutions:

1. You can use [configure a private ip on CloudSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-private-ip) and then reach it directly to this IP. For this, your GKE cluster must be configured as VPC native.
2. You can attach a sidecar to your main container which open a `cloud sql proxy` connection to your database. This solution is quite similar of the answer of @ParthMehta. Here the [description](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine) (and the [github example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes-engine-samples/blob/master/cloudsql/mysql_wordpress_deployment.yaml)) of this sidecar configuration

For Spanner, it's different because you can't use private IP or cloud SQL proxy binary. you have details on [this page for the configuration and the dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/use-hibernate)

As you can see, you connect your instance directly with the ressource definition (/projects/..../instance/.......). Your config file should look like to this:

```
db.driver=com.google.cloud.spanner.jdbc.JdbcDriver
db.url=jdbc:cloudspanner:/projects/{YOUR_PROJECT_ID}/instances/{YOUR_INSTANCE_ID}/databases/{YOUR_DATABASE_ID}
db.dialect=com.google.cloud.spanner.hibernate.SpannerDialect
```